# Spring: NullPointerException while injecting bean for a static property

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, static, spring-java-config

My main class is as follows:

```
package main;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import testbean.MySpringBeanWithDependency;

public class Main {

    public static MySpringBeanWithDependency mySpringBeanWithDependency;

    @Autowired
    public void setTest(MySpringBeanWithDependency mySpringBeanWithDependency) {
        Main.mySpringBeanWithDependency = mySpringBeanWithDependency;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        mySpringBeanWithDependency.run();
    }

}
```

And my AppConfig class is as follows:

```
package main;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import testbean.MySpringBeanWithDependency;
import writer.NiceWriter;
import writer.Writer;

@PropertySource("atm.properties")
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MySpringBeanWithDependency mySpringBeanWithDependency() {
        return new MySpringBeanWithDependency();
    }

    @Bean
    public Writer writer() {
        return new Writer();
    }

    @Bean 
    public NiceWriter niceWriter() {
        return new NiceWriter();
    }

}
```

Though I am instantiating the bean named mySpringBeanWithDependency and assigning it to the static field, the run() method command is throwing a NullPointerException.

I saw this workaround for injecting static fields in some answers but I guess it is not working for me. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong and how should I achieve this?

Comment: This is not the way dependency injection works. initializing static field is antipattern

Answer (score 1):

`Main` is not a bean, neither is it instantiated. I'm sure there might be a way to inject your bean into the static field but it would make much more sense to fetch the bean from the application context when you need it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    MySpringBeanWithDependency bean = context.getBean(MySpringBeanWithDependency.class);
    bean.run();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid getBean because I read in spring documentation that it should be avoided, its written in the last paragraph [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-client)

Comment: I didn't know its discouraged to use `getBean()`, thanks for clearing that up. In that case, I would suppose that the way to do it is, to just intialize the context, and annotate the `run()` Method with `@PostConstruct`, means it is called upon instanciation. If the bean is not `Lazy` it should run your application.
Can't tell if this is a better approach, tho.